# Nokogiri: why does this return only the removed tag and not the remainder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, nokogiri

Where `body` is this:

```
<img src='/Users/test/Documents/cd-rum/whatever/spec/factories/images/rda.jpg' />Et qui incidunt provident sed nemo modi pariatur quia.
```

Why does this:

```
parsed_body = Nokogiri::HTML(body).search('img').first.remove
parsed_body.to_html
```

Return *only* the image tag?

```
Failure/Error: specify { expect(post.parsed_body).to_not include('<img') }
expected "<img src=\"/Users/test/Documents/cd-rum/whatever/spec/factories/images/rda.jpg\">" not to include "<img"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're assigning the result of `.remove` to that variable - just remove the assignment

```
body = "<img src='/Users/test/Documents/cd-rum/whatever/spec/factories/images/rda.jpg' />Et qui incidunt provident sed nemo modi pariatur quia."
parsed_body = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(body)
parsed_body.search('img').first.remove
parsed_body.to_html # => "Et qui incidunt provident sed nemo modi pariatur quia."
```

Comment: Ah, total sense. Thank-you.